# Which matrix stack must be set as target when loading MVP matrix with glLoadMatrix

Tags: opengl, matrix, camera

Suppose I use the following code taken from GLM website to set the camera :

```
   glm::mat4 camera(float Translate, glm::vec2 const & Rotate)
   {
       glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(60.0f),float(width())/float(height()), 0.1f, 100.f);
       glm::mat4 View = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -Translate));
       View = glm::rotate(View, Rotate.y, glm::vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
       View = glm::rotate(View, Rotate.x, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
       glm::mat4 Model = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.5f));
       return Projection * View * Model;
   }
```

which matrix stack I must target  when I use the matrix resulting from the above function? Should I use

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
```

or

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

or should I just load the resulting matrix ?

Comment: Well it's unclear what your aiming for actually. The correct answer may be "any" or "neither". Is there any reason you are using the deprecated matrix stacks at all? Especially, as you seem to bypass the fixed function's default split between these matrices, which will break any fixed functionality based on eye-space calculations.

Comment: The reason I'm using the deprecated API is that I want to give the user the possibility to choose between old and modern rendering facilities, nothing more, nothing less. About the code, I chosen it because it offer a good pretext for my question.

Comment: Unless you're aiming for GPUs built before 2003 there's no benfit in providing a fixed function codepath. GLSL has been around since 2002 and drivers had semi-robust compilers in late 2003.

Comment: I think you are correct. Every thing you can do with the FF pipeline can be done better with GLSL, I know it. But while on one side I keep hearing FF pipeline is dead, on the other I am not aware of the existence of any graphics package that doesn't offer access to it or uses it in a way or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. The `Projection` Matrix goes into `GL_PROJECTION` and `View*Model` goes into `GL_MODELVIEW`. Of course that only applies to the fixed function pipeline. If using shaders it's completely up to you, specifically how you wrote your shaders.

Answer (score 1):

[There's some issues regarding normals and lighting behind the separation of the projection and modelview matrices](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/projection_abuse.php):

> Unfortunately, when someone does go and put their camera transform
>   into the GL_PROJECTION matrix (instead of into GL_MODELVIEW where it
>   belongs) - the consequences are rather subtle:
>
> - Lighting: OpenGL has to transform vertex normals into world coordinate space - that is to say WITHOUT the effects of perspective -
>     but WITH the effects of the camera position. Hence, only the
>     GL_MODELVIEW matrix is applied to the normals for lighting. If you put
>     the camera transform into the GL_PROJECTION matrix then your lighting
>     will be wrong. However, some people do their own lighting - and in any
>     case, it can be a subtle error that you might not have noticed
>     previously.
> - Fog: OpenGL has to figure out how far each vertex is from the camera. Once again, perspective effects are not relevent to this
>     calculation - so the GL_PROJECTION matrix is not used. If you put the
>     camera transform into the GL_PROJECTION matrix then your fogging will
>     be wrong. Since few people use fog, many people have the error and
>     don't know it.
> - TexGen: Since OpenGL uses the eyepoint to figure out some of the TexGen'ed texture coordinates, if the camera position is all mixed up
>     with the projection information then you'll end up with some pretty
>     strange texture coordinates. (Thanks to Brian Sharp at 3Dfx for
>     pointing this one out)
> - Z-buffer: I believe (but have no proof) that a screwed up GL_PROJECTION matrix could cause your Z values to be computed
>     strangely. This would likely only manifest itself as a lack of Z
>     precision under some circumstances - so you might not notice - and it
>     might not matter.